# How records are ordered when "order by" clause used with more then one entities

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

My query is:

```
select * from record order by name desc, tweet_count desc, time desc
```

Now how would be resulting record would be ordered?  There are some name record which comes first as per `desc` but for that tweet_count are lesser. confused

Answer (score 3):

It first orders the rows by name desc. Then if some records have the same name, it orders them by tweet_count desc, then if some records having the same name also have the same tweet_count, it orders them by time desc.

Answer (score 1):

Name would take priority in descending order. If someone had the same name, the the next field would be used to sort and so on

Answer (score 1):

The idea is simple: 
you will get list of records where name is ordered descending then tweet_count in descending order and also time desc.
Don't you get them like that?
Why are you confused?
Let me give an example, considering:

```
name|tweets|time
A 3 10(sec)
A 4 15
B 1 2
B 1 20 
A 4 20

The result would be:

B 1 20 
B 1 2
A 4 20
A 4 15
A 3 10(sec)
```